# Merge Tool that adds source layer as a field in Attribute Table

Tags: arcgis-pro, merge

I learned about Merge Tool recently that joins multiple layers and as much as it is useful when joining two layers, a different use case popped into my head at once.

Let's say we have many more layers that we want to join but we also want to preserve the source. For example:

| Object ID | ...Attributes... | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | <layer_name> |
| 2 |  | <layer_name2> |
| 3 |  | <another_layer> |

The workaround, or current way of doing it, would be to add this column to each layer. This could be quite time-consuming, hence I'm wondering if there's already a tool that does it for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not time consuming, you just need to read the help file! If you look at the last parameter of the [merge tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/merge.htm#GUID-7D7965A6-8486-4AF1-AAFD-C0168DFD1124) you can tick on the source the data is coming from. This functionality has been available since ArcGIS Pro 2.9